# is it possible make a next-PWA "install to home screen" install banner in every landing pages if the user missed the install prompt

Tags: progressive-web-apps, next-pwa

I want the user to get the install to home screen prompt events in case they  when they missed the prompt  or declined to install to home screen.
Should be automatically triggered.
using the NEXT-PWA  for NEXt.js

using  next-PWA its not possible. kindly share your solutions